# How to avoid naming conflicts or collsions with Salesforce unlocked packages

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

In Java or C# or similar languages there is the package/namespace structure to avoid collisions between class names. With Salesforce unlocked packages where there are multiple projects within a domain and the best practice (per most of what I have read) being a separate project per package, how do you prevent naming collisions between components when working with a large and/or distributed team? Hoping there is an answer beyond "governance" :)

Comment: Unlocked packages can use namespaces if you need to ? Is there anything else you are looking ?

Comment: Namespaces are fine for distributing packages to other orgs. My question is about avoiding collisions between development teams within the same namespace or org. Updated the question text for further clarity.

Comment: why are they using the same org? Should it be not that each team uses different org ? Also an org can have multiple packages with different namespaces.They should be using different scartch orgs. Namespace is also not just for distribution . You can use it to add a namespace to a scratch org.

Comment: Three years on, but did you ever get any more clarity on this issue? When pushing unlocked packages to an org, it looks like a packages contents are not scoped in any way. From what I can tell, incoming files will simply overwrite existing files, even if they are from different packages.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion I have come to is to have a namespace per repository and some standards are folder structure. Not perfect, but will handle most situations.

Comment: How about assigning each package/team unique artificial prefix (e.g. region based, like NA_, EU_), and ask them to use it when creating objects, fields, classes etc. It is like emulating SF namespace, but without actually using one. Also you may implement some validation at CI/CD level to fail pipeline if naming convention is not followed for artifacts created in current MR/PR.